# Rails process controls to delay/impede multiple submissions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

An application is based upon client's use and thus network connections.  Sometimes, some processes are longer (i.e. capturing a hand-written line, converting to JSON, generating image and uploading to a static server), which can be compounded via flaky web connections.

Overanxious users may believe something is wrong and continue submitting... making the situation worse.

For specific actions, say `update_signature`, how could one conceivably trash other requests for that particular action and unique identifier ?

Answer (score 1):

You can handle rate limiting with [Rack::Throttle](https://github.com/dryruby/rack-throttle). And debounce double clicks (convert to a single click) with javascript.

But don't optimize prematurely.